# Getting the real Facebook user id from a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the app scoped user id for my Facebook app using the graph api but I need the real user id to send notifications. Or is there a way to send notification using the app scoped user id?

Note: I've seen several similar questions asked but no answer has been given.

Comment: that question gets asked a lot, and there is always an answer: it´s not possible to get the real id. if there would be a way, the whole point of app scoped ids would be void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not get the real user id.  Yes, you can send notifications with the app-scoped id if your application is on the Facebook canvas.  I do it in my apps.

Comment: How exactly do you do it? I'm using this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/notifications
But when it throws an error when I use the app scoped user id

Comment: You're app is a canvas app, right?  It should work as detailed there if so.  It's the same thing I use.

Comment: that is NOT the correct reference link. this is how you send app notifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

Comment: @luschn unless I'm mistaken it does explain how to publish notifications on that same page he posted.  I use the same code.  Your link provides more detail though.

Comment: Yes. I was my mistake. I was using the older version of the API and so it was expecting the real user id. Thanks @Phillip!